# Display Video on JupyterLab Notebook on GCP

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am having trouble display/embedding a video in a Notebook in Jupyter Lab. I have tried multiple ways to display a video, but it just does not play the video. The player loads but does not load the video. I am using JupyterLab on a Google Cloud (GCP) VM.

Attempt 1:

```
from IPython.display import Video

Video(LOCAL_PATH)
```

Attempt 2:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""
    <video alt="test" controls>
        <source src="./video.mov" type="video/mov">
    </video>
""")
```

Attempt 3:

```
%%html
    <video width='480' height='480' controls>
        <source src='./video.mov'>
    </video>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a code cell and use the following code and works for youtube, a MP4 video and .mov video.
My videos are ~2 MBs each. Are you loading a large video?

```
%%HTML
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3SeRMd0tGms?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```
from IPython.display import Video
Video("video.mp4")
```

```
from IPython.display import Video
Video("movie.mov")
```

[image]

Comment: The videos are relatively big, around 50 mb to 300 mb.

Comment: is same code working in your Notebooks for smaller videos?

Comment: I will try with a larger video and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah I have tried the same code and it's still not displaying

Comment: What NB instance flavor are you using? I used a brand new TF 1.15

Comment: @gogasca Is there any solution to load a large video in Colab or JupyterLab? Colab always loads the player but do not load the large video.

Answer (score 0):

I also has the same problem with JupyterLab. The IPython.display and %%HTML solution do not work for me.
Then, I used moviepy library instead. It solved the problem.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

path="you_video_file_path" 

clip=VideoFileClip(path)
clip.ipython_display(width=500)
```